# How can I add small image on top of another image in outlook to make small image as hyperlink in Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-word, ms-office, html-email, outlook-2010

I'm creating a poster for an email.
I have a one [image]big image-

and one small image-

[image]

I want to put the small one on top of another and insert a hyperlink like below.

[image]

When the next person receives the mail, the position of the smaller images changes and it is visible properly only when the mail is expanded(maximized).

How do I fix this?

Comment: What HTML markup is used for the layout in Outlook?